# c++ : how can I fourier transform an array into an other array of different size using fftw3

Tags: c++, c, fft, convolution, fftw

I need to fourier transform an array with integer-values to the frequency domain (in order to multiply it with another one later). The output array must have the size of 44100 but the input array will vary.

I think fftw3 is a good tool for that. But how do I create a 'plan' with different array-sizes for input and output?

here is the function I wrote:

```
fftw_complex* fourier( int* samples, int numberOfSamples ){

    fftw_complex* input;
    fftw_complex* output;
    fftw_plan plan;
    input = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc( sizeof(fftw_complex)*numberOfSamples );
    output = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc( sizeof(fftw_complex)*44100 );                  //cd-quality

    plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d( 44100, input, output, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE );
    // here is the problem because  ^this
    // array has a different size than
    //                                     ^this array

    for( size_t index = 0; index < numberOfSamples; index++ ){
        input[index][0] = (double)(samples[index]);
        input[index][1] = 0;
    }
    fftw_execute(plan);
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
    fftw_free(input);
    return output;
}
```

thanks a lot for answering

Comment: `44100` looks like some kind of audio sampling rate. Normally sizes of `fft` arrays have nothing to do with sampling rates and are power-of-two. Usually input and output array sizes match because of the mathematical requirement. If size of real input data doesn't match array size, there are techniques of windowing and zero-padding to fix this. There's enough good literature on this subject.

Comment: others have already mentioned that the input and output length must match. maybe you could give a bit more context on what you're trying to do. based on that magic number it looks like you're trying to estimate the power spectrum with 1 bin per Hz (probably). If that's the case you just need to zero pad your input up to 44100 samples and apply a window function (try hanning) to the block of input you have to smooth out the spectrum.

Answer (score 3):

The discrete fourier transform will always produce an output with the same size as its input, as a basic mathematical premise of the algorithm, and this is reflected in FFTW by only taking in one size parameter. This is because for an array of N discrete values in the time domain, there are exactly N possible unique frequencies at play, from 0 to N-1 cycles per unit of time (this unit being the length in time of your input).

You could scale your input up or down in size to 44100 values, by essentially stretching the input and interpolating its values to create a new array that fits the required length, and then perform the fourier transform. I recommend you perform this stretching on the input time domain and not on the frequency domain to avoid undesirable artifacts.

Comment: Is a linear interpolation the best thing you can do?  I mean, suppose you took the samples, produced a sum of sinusodials that best approximated the signal, then used that to interpolate?  That corresponds to a relatively simple transformation in the frequency domain, and might be a better method?

Comment: @Yakk wouldn't that accomplish the same thing, just not in n*log(n) time?

Comment: you can't just stretch the input, that will cause obvious artifacts. if you actually need to interpolate (i don't see why you would do that at all here, given that it changes the bin meaning entirely) you should do it against a nyquist limited pulse shape. If you care about performance you should do this in the frequency domain, since its cheaper (single tap). if you're really worried about artifacts in the frequency domain pad out the transform to turn the circular convolution into a normal one, same as overlap&save method

Comment: @SteveCox I believe you know much more about convolution than I do :) you should provide an answer too, or feel free to edit mine

Comment: @tim no, a linear interpolation has a rather complex frequency response (it is like convolving with a triangle, which is obviously not simple in the frequency domain).  (My knowledge of this field is abstract, not practical, so I do not know the best answer, I can just spot issues)